# EPS to SVG Conversion for PDF output

Tags: java, svg, imagemagick, apache-fop, eps

I have all eps files as input and these eps files are present in my xml file.

```
<?xml>
<FIGURE>
    <L-GRAPHIC L="DE">
        <GRAPHIC FILENAME="abc.eps">
        </GRAPHIC>
    </L-GRAPHIC>
</FIGURE>
</xml>
```

**Java code usign ImageMagick**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputfileName = "C:\\abc.eps"; 

    try {
        System.out.println("Started" + inputfileName);
        ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(inputfileName);

        MagickImage magick_converter = new MagickImage(info);

        String outputfile = "C:\\abc.svg"; // Output File name
        magick_converter.setFileName(outputfile);

        magick_converter.writeImage(info);
        System.out.println("Complete");

    } catch (MagickException e1) {          
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

**Current output with above code:**

```
Started
```

Nothing happens after that.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer

The ImageMagick solutions does not create vector outputs but pixel file formats. It might solve the problem though. The only, open source, way, I found, to create a svg image from eps is the Inkscape method mentioned briefly below.

EDIT: @Chai has found a solution by himself, see elsewhere on this page.

### Manual pre-process

With the open source utility software [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) you can easily convert from one image format to another. In its easiest form just do:

```
convert image.eps image.png
```

With use of switches you can tweak the quality and a lot of other features as well.

With the open source drawing software [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/download/) you can do the same manually. Simply open the eps image and save it as a svg image file.

### Programmatical process

This is one way to solve this using java. The solution is based on the [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) ImageMagick wrapper. In my case there was no need to connect my ImageMagick installation to the java library but if that is the case; how is mentioned on their web-site.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.im4java.core.ConvertCmd;
import org.im4java.core.IM4JavaException;
import org.im4java.core.IMOperation;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, IM4JavaException {
    ConvertCmd convertCmd = new ConvertCmd();

    IMOperation imOperation = new IMOperation();

    imOperation.addImage("/home/user/images/image.eps");
    imOperation.addImage("/home/user/images/image.png");

    convertCmd.run(imOperation);
}
```

#### The pom.xml if you are using maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>imagemagick</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.im4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>im4java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I used ImageMagick. Please see my code above. I tried executing my java class. But nothing happens. Please help.

Comment: Hi..I executed your code. I am getting this error :" Invalid Parameter - abc.svg". I think I should tell you the background. This whole thing is required because, Apache FOP does not support eps files in pdf output. The inputs to my FOP(xml input) has 'FIGURE' tags which are all eps files and hence before parsing the xml and sending output to the pdf, i need to convert eps to svg. I am using xslt to style every tag and send it to pdf. Is my approach of doing conversion in java is correct? Is there a better way? Please please help.

Comment: Is the filename you get an absolute path existing in your machine or accessible through the net? I have tested the code above with an url to an image file instead of an absolute file path on disk and it works. I've been on the same track as you before and my plan was to do some programmatical conversion beforehand. Keep in mind though that your result file has to be accessible to the fop process.

Comment: Hi..I have the file in my local dir. I am using eclipse IDE. I have installed jre6 32 bit. Im4java 1.4 jar. Also installed ImageMagick. Is there anything I am missing here? It is still the same error. :(

Comment: I think the problem is with setting up environment variable. I added the below statements: String myPath="C:\\ImageMagick\\im4java-1.4.0\\bin";
ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(myPath); It is trying to search for convert command and I am getting " org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: convert" error.

Comment: First, im4java needs to find ImageMagick not itself. Read this page http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html and try to fulfill it to the letter. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the proper solution for this. I used pstoedit.exe and ghostscript to convert eps files to svg format in my java code.
Thank you.

Comment: Very nice, this I will be using as well. The pstoedit converter is also available through popular packaging tools for linux like apt-get, yum and so fourth. I just tried it and it made a beautiful conversion, keeping transparency, with a smaller file foot print.